# Colloquial American term for "miliaria"

Tags: american-english, vocabulary, slang, colloquialisms

Often during summers in the tropics, especially under intense heat conditions, we get a skin condition medically referred to as "miliaria." It comprises of reddish rashes with several tiny boil-like eruptions. These are not harmful and go away once the heat dies down but are mighty irritating.

People generally apply talcum powder for some temporary relief. I need to know the most commonly used term for this condition in America. Wikipedia gives terms like "prickly heat," "sweat rash," and "heat rash." Which of these, if any, would an average American prefer?

Here's an image for illustration:

[image: Image of rash]

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miliaria

Comment: Personally, I find "heat rash" to be the most recognizable phrase of the three you listed.

Comment: @Mitch: I doubt you read the question because I have already listed the terms given by Wikipedia and my question is about the "colloquial American" preference of the three.

Comment: Sorry, yes, then 'heat rash' is preferred.

Answer (score 3):

In the [written record](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=heat%20rash%2Cprickly%20heat%2Csweat%20rash&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cheat%20rash%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprickly%20heat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csweat%20rash%3B%2Cc0) of American English, both *prickly heat* and *heat rash* are used significantly more than *sweat rash*:

[image]

The fact that *heat rash* has been gaining usage in the written record may reveal the stubborn American tendency to eschew [British](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=heat%20rash%2Cprickly%20heat%2Csweat%20rash&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cheat%20rash%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprickly%20heat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csweat%20rash%3B%2Cc0) colloquialism, but it offers no proof that it has overtaken the historical dominance of *prickly heat*.